# Find shortest path using GremlinPipeline

Tags: java, gremlin, titan

My data is stored in a Titan graph database. I am trying to find the shortest path between two vertices (v1 and v2). Currently I have the following code:

```
    final Vertex v1 = titanGraph.getVertices("nodeId", "110969224").iterator().next();
    final Vertex v2 = titanGraph.getVertices("nodeId", "141396276").iterator().next();
    System.out.println(v2);

    final GremlinPipeline<String, List> pipe = new GremlinPipeline<String, List>(v1)
            .as("similar")
            .both("similar")
            .loop("similar", new PipeFunction<LoopBundle<Vertex>, Boolean>() {
                @Override
                public Boolean compute(LoopBundle<Vertex> bundle) {
                    return bundle.getLoops() < 4 && bundle.getObject() != v2;
                }
            })  
            .path();
```

which returns alls the paths. I have the following questions:

- Is this tha fastest way to find the shortest path?
- How can I get the shortest of all these paths?

EDIT:
I am trying to do the same work but with GremlinGroovyScriptEngine. I have the following code:

```
    List results = new ArrayList();
    Bindings bindings = engine.createBindings();
    bindings.put("v1", v1); 
    bindings.put("v2", v2); 
    bindings.put("results", results);

    engine.eval("v1.both.filter{it.nodeId!='nodeId'}.loop('similar'){!it.object.equals(v2) && it.loop < 5}.paths.fill(results)", bindings);
```

but I get the following error:

```
Exception in thread "main" javax.script.ScriptException: javax.script.ScriptException: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at com.tinkerpop.gremlin.groovy.jsr223.GremlinGroovyScriptEngine.eval(GremlinGroovyScriptEngine.java:94)
    at javax.script.AbstractScriptEngine.eval(AbstractScriptEngine.java:233)
    at TitanQuery.findShortestPath(TitanQuery.java:89)
    at TitanQuery.main(TitanQuery.java:40)
Caused by: javax.script.ScriptException: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at com.tinkerpop.gremlin.groovy.jsr223.GremlinGroovyScriptEngine.eval(GremlinGroovyScriptEngine.java:221)
    at com.tinkerpop.gremlin.groovy.jsr223.GremlinGroovyScriptEngine.eval(GremlinGroovyScriptEngine.java:90)
    ... 3 more
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at com.tinkerpop.pipes.branch.LoopPipe.getLoops(LoopPipe.java:75)
    at com.tinkerpop.pipes.branch.LoopPipe.processNextStart(LoopPipe.java:49)
    at com.tinkerpop.pipes.AbstractPipe.next(AbstractPipe.java:89)
    at com.tinkerpop.pipes.transform.PropertyPipe.processNextStart(PropertyPipe.java:29)
    at com.tinkerpop.pipes.AbstractPipe.next(AbstractPipe.java:89)
    at com.tinkerpop.pipes.util.Pipeline.next(Pipeline.java:115)
    at com.tinkerpop.pipes.util.PipeHelper.fillCollection(PipeHelper.java:52)
    at com.tinkerpop.gremlin.java.GremlinPipeline.fill(GremlinPipeline.java:1575)
    at com.tinkerpop.gremlin.java.GremlinFluentPipeline$fill.call(Unknown Source)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.CallSiteArray.defaultCall(CallSiteArray.java:42)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.call(AbstractCallSite.java:108)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.call(AbstractCallSite.java:116)
    at Script1.run(Script1.groovy:1)
    at com.tinkerpop.gremlin.groovy.jsr223.GremlinGroovyScriptEngine.eval(GremlinGroovyScriptEngine.java:219)
    ... 4 more
```

Any advice for any of these issues would be great.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your code looks to be somewhat similar to the the shortest path recipe in GremlinDocs:

http://gremlindocs.com/#recipes/shortest-path

You might want to read that section in full as you are evaluating `both` directions of a vertex which has consequences and has been shown to be better handled with the store/except pattern.

Once you have all the paths need to just select the shortest one from the returned list.  In pure Java that's a bit more work than with Groovy, but it basically boils down to a sort on the path length and then choosing the shortest one.  In groovy that would be something like:

```
gremlin> g.v(1).out.loop(1){it.object.id != "3" && it.loops < 6}.path.sort{a,b->a.size()<=>b.size()}   
==>[v[1], v[3]]
==>[v[1], v[4], v[3]]
```

Looking at that made me wonder if you could always just pop-off the first item in the pipeline as it would be the earliest path detected and hence the shortest:

```
gremlin> g.v(1).out.loop(1){it.object.id != "3" && it.loops < 6}.path[0]                            
==>[v[1], v[3]]
```

You might want to experiment with that a bit, but it sounds like a promising theory that would allow you to short-circuit the pipeline if you just needed the first shortest path detected.

Comment: You think the performance will be worst if I use this [this](https://github.com/tinkerpop/gremlin/wiki/Using-Gremlin-through-Java#using-jsr-223-gremlingroovyscriptengine), with which I can use groovy ?

Comment: I exclusively use gremlin-groovy on all production projects.  It performs well with minimal overhead except for avoidable cases such as use of reflection to get property names.  I'd always recommend starting with gremlin-groovy then swapping to java in off cases if you find that you absolutely must optimize.  Having a maven-based project will make co-mingling java/groovy completely seamless.  I'd recommend giving it a try.

Comment: Ok, I'll try this solution and I'll come back if I have problems. Thanks

Comment: not sure if this is the only problem, but you are looping to "similar" but it doesn't appear to be defined in a `as` step.  Note that my suggestion to work with Groovy applied more to including Groovy class files in your project.  An integrated Maven project is a common pattern for me, not an embedded script engine.  That said, an embedded script engine is exactly how Rexster works, so what you are doing is certainly possible.  The issue is that you have a lot of code (Gremlin) embedded as strings which isn't as maintainable as actual Groovy class files in your project.